# Scroll in android using touchAction in webdriverio (javascript)

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android

I am trying to scroll the android screen using touchAction in webdriverio. Am using the following code to perform action but it doesn't work.

`driver.touchAction([ {action:'press',x:1052,y:1567}, { action: 'moveTo',x:1041, y:689}, 'release' ])`

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Try using `longPress` instead of `press`. You may also need to preface the command with `await` due to to asynchronous nature. For example:

```
await driver.touchAction([ {action: 'longPress', x: 0, y: 1000}, { action: 'moveTo', x: 0, y: 10}, 'release' ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `touchAction`, the `touchPerform` can chain operations altogether.

```
await driver.touchPerform([
    { action: "longPress", options: { x: 414, y: 1285 } },
    { action: "moveTo", options: { x: 427, y: 226 } },
    { action: "release", options: {} },
    {
      action: "wait",
      options: {
        ms: 100,
      },
    },
    { action: "longPress", options: { x: 414, y: 1285 } },
    { action: "moveTo", options: { x: 427, y: 226 } },
    { action: "release", options: {} },
  ]);
```

Comment: Appium `2.4.1`, WebdriverIO `8.30.0`, getting `ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 405 due to unknown method: Not implemented` when trying to `.touchPerform()`